# $this->getChildHtml('before_body_end') won't render in new page template

Tags: template, xml

Magento CE 1.7.0.1

I've created a new 1column.phtml template file which I have set to be used by my templates catalog.xml file:

```
<!--
Product view
-->

    <catalog_product_view>
        <!-- Mage_Catalog -->
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
```

After that I proceeded to test a few changes but I noticed that not everything was being loaded in my browser window. It seemed to stop immediately after the footer so I view the rendered page source in my browser and I see that my page stops rendering immediately before:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('before_body_end') ?>
```

The page will load without any problems if I remove that line. I check in the log files of Magento and I see nothing. I check what I believe to be the php error log for the site and I see nothing there as well. Any theories as to why Magento would stop when asked to getChildHtml? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean that it doesn't complete the closing `body` tag? That normally *would* indicate an exception. I guess it's possible that your errors are being written to a location other than where you expect to see them.

Anyway, you should start inspecting what other blocks are being stuffed into the `before_body_end` handle. On a *nix system, you should be able to do:

`grep -rn 'before_body_end' /path/to/mage/app/design/frontend`

And that may help you to identify which child block is causing the error.

Another tip is to install an extension like [Alan Storm's Layoutviewer module](http://alanstorm.com/layouts_blocks_and_templates). It will let you see the generated layout XML before page render just by appending a query param to your target page URL.